# IDHTTP.Post error

Tags: delphi, indy, idhttp

```
procedure Texport_plan.cxB_LoadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Query: String;
  Buffer: TMemoryStream;
  loadData: Sting;
  responseData: String; 
begin 
  try
    HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    HTTP.Request.ContentEncoding := 'utf-8';
    HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml';
    Application.ProcessMessages;

    Query := 'http://priem.edu.ru:8000/import/ImportService.svc/import';
    loadData := '<Root></Root>'

    Buffer := TMemoryStream.Create;
    loadData.SaveToStream(Buffer);
    responseData := HTTP.Post(Query, Buffer);
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

This returns HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request. If use get from http://priem.edu.ru:8000/import/ImportService.svc/test/import
i get right xml document in response.  Why could this happen? I checked all i can find in google...but nothing helps.

Im using RAD Delphi XE3

**UPD:** Test client works fine...C# + webclient class. May be something more exists for delphi...not only IdHTTP?

Comment: did you tried sendign it to http://priem.edu.ru:8000/import/ImportService.svc/help/operations/DoValidate ?
did you tried putting your loadData through XML validator ? https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=xml+validator&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest

the site claims it must get XML on input, so give it XML, not SGML

Comment: Validate is not XML validator =) it checks data to be correct in tags =) Adding <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> changes nothing =(

Comment: And they have their test client...it works fine with <root></root>

Comment: with <root> or with <Root> ?

Comment: Sure, thus their validator and XML validator are two different advices. Each of those detect different kind of errors, but both should report you some errors to be fixed, different errors as they validate agaisnt different crtieria

Comment: Presumably, it happens because you're sending a bad request. You have a test program that works. Use Wire Shark to observe a good request from that program and a bad request from yours. What's different between them, and how can you make yours behave more like the good one?

Comment: r or R doesnt matter =) it will be error about some other tags.

Comment: Seems to be identical =(

Comment: *r or R doesnt matter* Howcan you know it ? i thought that was XML and you say that is kinda HTML...

Comment: It will return error from service...like no Root element. But i am getting bad request. And i use same data in my programm and their client...but errors are different...I think may be bad connection options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

It turned out that the assignment order of the `Charset` and `ContentType` is important.

If you use a `ContentType` containing the `xml`, `xml-external-parsed-entity` *words* or ending with `+xml`, the Charset is forcibly set to the value `'us-ascii'` and to `'ISO-8859-1'` in all other cases.

The behavior is undocumented, so you're free to think it is a bug or an implementation detail.

Comments from Remy in the body of `TIdEntityHeaderInfo.SetContentType` (`IdHTTPHeaderInfo.pas`) say:

> // RLebeau: per RFC 3023 Sections 3.1, 3.3, 3.6, and 8.5:
>      //
>      // Conformant with [RFC2046], if a text/xml entity is received with
>      // the charset parameter omitted, MIME processors and XML processors
>      // MUST use the default charset value of "us-ascii"[ASCII].  In cases
>      // where the XML MIME entity is transmitted via HTTP, the default
>      // charset value is still "us-ascii".  (Note: There is an
>      // inconsistency between this specification and HTTP/1.1, which uses
>      // ISO-8859-1[ISO8859] as the default for a historical reason.  Since
>      // XML is a new format, a new default should be chosen for better
>      // I18N.  US-ASCII was chosen, since it is the intersection of UTF-8
>      // and ISO-8859-1 and since it is already used by MIME.)

To change the charset, you must set it after setting the `ContentType` value, like this:

```
HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml';
HTTP.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';
```

**Original answer**
(still valid)

You're indicating your content is encoded in `utf-8`, but Delphi strings are `utf-16` encoded by default.

I have no Delphi at hand to check if the string helper have a overloaded version of the `SaveToStream` method which supports encodings, but I bet it have, so you can try:

```
loadData.SaveToStream(Buffer, TEncoding.UTF8);
```

before sending your data.

Comment: I tried this before. Checked again...no result. The most interesting thing that packages from test client and my programm are equal except: identification, sequence namuber, acknowledgement number, and Src Port. After i launched several times test client i can see...that only source port is constant. So it can be only a problem...but as for me it doent really matter from what port i send data.

Comment: Hmmm...changing order really helps...Tnx for this advise. About ansi-ascii i make a mistake...you mentioned it right. I will mark ur answer as best.

Answer (score 0):

I found error. If content type is */xml IdHTTP changes Charset to 'us-ansi'...
To make this component works properly you need to change

```
HTTP.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';
HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml';
```

to

```
HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml; charset=utf-8';
```

So IdHTTP cant change Charset to us-ansi and you will get encoding you want.

Comment: -1 for calling _stupid component_ the one that you got free of charge.  IMHO If you fund a bug, you go to the project devs, thank them for the effort and inform about your finding, how it is wrong and how to resolve it.

Comment: i spent 2 days to find this thing. And it is not a bug...it was coded to be so. i dont think that if 'xml' then := ansi is a mistake... And by the way...i think you will agree...if u type something := 'xxx' then you want xxx not yyy without any reason

Comment: If it is coded that way, either it is a bug, or it is because some RFC rule. Remy from the Indy Team usually know that very well. And, believe it or not, you got Indy for free, since it is a open source project. The fact that it is included in the standard Embarcadero installation doesn't make it part of the product you buy. For more info visit http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/index.EN.aspx

Comment: Can you please tell me where Indy is doing the change you describe? a quick search for `us-ansi` and `/xml` retrieves nothing from the Indy source.

Comment: Well, I found it and looking at the code it turns out that the assignment order is important, and the charset forcibly set is **`us-ascii`** (and not `us-ansi` as you stated). The behavior is undocumented, so you may consider it a bug or just a implementation detail. All the reasons to do so are in the comments of the `TIdEntityHeaderInfo.SetContentType` method body (IdHTTPHeaderInfo.pas).

Invert the assignment order, don't use the assignment you suggest (all in ContentType) since other INDY parts may depend on the value of this property and is supposed you store the real ContentType alone